# How can I hide an app from the dock while keeping it in the menu bar?

Tags: applications, dock, menu-bar

There's a messaging app I often use that includes both a menu bar icon (to hide/show the window, as well as indicate how many unread messages there are) as well as the app itself which resides in the dock/launchpad.

I want to know if there's a way to hide the app from my dock when the app is running so that I can simply use the menu bar to see if I have any new messages and thus save dock space. I know that this is possible as some of my other apps already do this (e.g. [LastPass for Mac](https://www.lastpass.com/)), but is there a way to do this manually, e.g. through the Terminal? I am currently on MacOS Catalina Beta (although I assume the solution should also work for earlier versions too).

Comment: Just tried this (had to forcefully add write permission using `sudo chmod`) but now the app won't run. I think it's because it knows it's been modified so whatever validation MacOS does before it runs certified apps now fails. Thank you for the suggestion though! It'll be helpful when I hopefully get into MacOS development in the near future :D

Update: I wouldn't suggest anyone else to try this because I don't know how to revert it back now—had to delete and reinstall the app!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know if there's a way to hide the app from my dock when the app is running so that I can simply use the menu bar to see if I have any new messages and thus save dock space

An app can be configured to hide it's Dock icon, and show it only in the Menu bar, **only** if it is designed (programmed) to provide this functionality. If the app doesn't include this feature, it's not possible for user to achieve this by any other means (OS built-in or using any 3rd party tool).

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you very much for the quick response! I found a related question on how to do this as a developer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620841/how-to-hide-the-dock-icon), and it seems like that's the only way to do it (i.e. not user-changeable), like you said. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

A couple months ago I was able achieve this by:

Opening Macintosh HD>Applications

Right click desired app

Click "show package contents"

Open "Info.plist"

Then add

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>

<string>1</string>
```

in the middle of the document.

Save it and voila.

However, this randomly stopped working a couple months ago.. The Info.plist file just gets rewritten when I open the app. Maybe it'll still work for you.

Comment: This no longer works with signed apps in the last several release of macOS. This will only work on unsigned apps and ones created by the user. Additionally, in a now deleted comment to the OP, I suggested it and it didn't work for him as mentioned in his reply comment and had to reinstall the app after attempting this.

Comment: I just tried this method on TopTracker app and it worked. Although it's info.plist was inside content folder.